# how to change csv filename variable in profile action xml of Dataflow-Advanced profile on run time?

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.9

I want to use Dataflow-Advanced profile to import the csv from frontend. i have googled and find a stand-alone script for that, but problem is that now this script work only for fixed csv file. I want to change the csv file name on run time to import through stand-alone script. Please refer screen-shot link https://www.diigo.com/item/image/5hhy6/7pxw?size=o to more clear. Could anyone help me to get achieve this?

Here is sample script:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");
Mage::app()->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML,
Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_TRANSLATE);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');
$localeName = "en_US";
Mage::app()->getLocale()->setDefaultLocale($localeName);
Mage::app()->getLocale()->setLocale($localeName);
Mage::app()->getLocale()->setLocaleCode($localeName);
setlocale(LC_ALL, Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode());
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
Mage::app()->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_TRANSLATE);

Mage::app();
$profileId = 11; //put your profile id here
$logFileName= date("j-n-Y")."-import.log";
$recordCount = 0;
Mage::log("Import Started",null,$logFileName);
$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);
if ($profileId) {
    $profile->load($profileId);
    if (!$profile->getId()) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('The profile you are trying to save no longer exists');
    }
}
Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
$profile->run();
$batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');
if ($batchModel->getId()) {
    if ($batchModel->getAdapter()) {
        $batchId = $batchModel->getId();
        $batchImportModel = $batchModel->getBatchImportModel();
        $importIds = $batchImportModel->getIdCollection();
        $batchModel = Mage::getModel('dataflow/batch')->load($batchId);
        $adapter = Mage::getModel($batchModel->getAdapter());
        $adapter->setBatchParams($batchModel->getParams());
        foreach ($importIds as $importId) {
            $recordCount++;
            try{
                $batchImportModel->load($importId);
                if (!$batchImportModel->getId()) {
                    $errors[] = Mage::helper('dataflow')->__('Skip undefined row');
                    continue;
                }
                $importData = $batchImportModel->getBatchData();
                try {
                    $adapter->saveRow($importData);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::log($e->getMessage(),null,$logFileName);
                    continue;
                }
                if ($recordCount%20 == 0) {
                    Mage::log($recordCount . ' - Completed!!',null,$logFileName);
                }
            } catch(Exception $ex) {
                Mage::log('Record# ' . $recordCount . ' - Error - ' . $ex->getMessage(),null,$logFileName);
            }
        }   
        foreach ($profile->getExceptions() as $e) {
            Mage::log($e->getMessage(),null,$logFileName);
        }
    }
}
Mage::log("Import Completed",null,$logFileName);
```

Looking forward for positive response!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");
Mage::app()->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML,
Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_TRANSLATE);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');
$localeName = "en_US";
Mage::app()->getLocale()->setDefaultLocale($localeName);
Mage::app()->getLocale()->setLocale($localeName);
Mage::app()->getLocale()->setLocaleCode($localeName);
setlocale(LC_ALL, Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode());
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
Mage::app()->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_TRANSLATE);

Mage::app();
$profileId = 11; //put your profile id here
$logFileName= date("j-n-Y")."-import.log";
$recordCount = 0;
Mage::log("Import Started",null,$logFileName);
$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);
if ($profileId) {
    $profile->load($profileId);
    if (!$profile->getId()) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('The profile you are trying to save no longer exists');
    }
//code to change the csv file name :: START

    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($profile->getData('actions_xml')); echo "</pre>";   
    $str = $profile->getData('actions_xml');
    $newCsv = 'import_products_new.csv'; // put your logic to get new file name as per your requirement 
    $new_action_xml = str_replace('import_products_old.csv', $newCsv, $str); //'import_products_old.csv' using static, as we know filename in already saved profile
    $profile->setActionsXml($new_action_xml);

//code to change the csv file name :: END 

}
Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
$profile->run();
$batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');
if ($batchModel->getId()) {
    if ($batchModel->getAdapter()) {
        $batchId = $batchModel->getId();
        $batchImportModel = $batchModel->getBatchImportModel();
        $importIds = $batchImportModel->getIdCollection();
        $batchModel = Mage::getModel('dataflow/batch')->load($batchId);
        $adapter = Mage::getModel($batchModel->getAdapter());
        $adapter->setBatchParams($batchModel->getParams());
        foreach ($importIds as $importId) {
            $recordCount++;
            try{
                $batchImportModel->load($importId);
                if (!$batchImportModel->getId()) {
                    $errors[] = Mage::helper('dataflow')->__('Skip undefined row');
                    continue;
                }
                $importData = $batchImportModel->getBatchData();
                try {
                    $adapter->saveRow($importData);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::log($e->getMessage(),null,$logFileName);
                    continue;
                }
                if ($recordCount%20 == 0) {
                    Mage::log($recordCount . ' - Completed!!',null,$logFileName);
                }
            } catch(Exception $ex) {
                Mage::log('Record# ' . $recordCount . ' - Error - ' . $ex->getMessage(),null,$logFileName);
            }
        }   
        foreach ($profile->getExceptions() as $e) {
            Mage::log($e->getMessage(),null,$logFileName);
        }
    }
}
Mage::log("Import Completed",null,$logFileName);
```

Hope this helps someone!

Thanks!